# Oracle APEX. Display and keep in sync the same database field twice on the same page

Tags: apex

I have a single page with multiple tabs.  I want some of the fields to be duplicated across tabs.
using APEX 23.2

I created a 2nd field/derived and assigned the database field to it.  But, the two fields are not kept in sync.  And, only the database field updates the database.  How can I keep them both in sync?  And do the update.